# Why is PHP updating the data not selected?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Hi I'm trying to update a column in the table. I've selected a range within the column, and used foreach to loop through them. However, I noticed that it not only updated the range I selected, but also outside the selection. Some advice appreciated!

Code:

```
$this->db->where('weekday', 5);
$this->db->where('source', 'site');

$record = $this->db->get('user', 200);

$print_r($record->num_rows());

foreach ($record->result() as $row) :
    $data = array(
        'weekday' => 1,
    );

    $this->db->where('user_id', $row->user_id); //added based on an answer provided below
    $this->db->update('user', $data);

endforeach;
```

This indeed look straightforward, and I did get from the print_r that I selected 200 rows.But the code actually updated all 3000 rows within the table which I did not select in the $record variable. How could this happen?

Thanks,

Update: many people tried and we still failed to track the problem. Could you pls help think of another way to get the job done without using foreach?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm using codeigniter and this is the way to define criteria before pulling out data. Plus I used print_r to confirm that I only pulled 200 rows

Comment: Update: I tried running: $this->db->last_query() after the endforeach, results say the last query is: "UPDATE `user` SET `weekday` = 1".

Answer (score 0):

Put the line:

```
$this->db->update('user', $data);
```

outside of the foreach

```
foreach ($record->result() as $row) {
        $data=array
            (
                'weekday'=>1,
            );

}
$this->db->update('user', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// SELECT * FROM 'user' WHERE 'weekday' = 5 AND 'source' = 'site' LIMIT 200
$this->db->where(['weekday' => 5, 'source' => 'site']);
$record = $this->db->get('user', 200);

foreach($record->result() as $row) {
    // UPDATE 'user' SET  'weekday' = 1 WHERE 'user_id' = {$row->user_id}
    $this->db->update('user', ['weekday' => 1], ['user_id' => $row->user_id]);
};
```

Try this, ps: don't quote me on this code, it was some time since I coded last for PHP

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. You cannot limit what the update function does. It will do the update for all rows in the table despite the foreach function. In order to accomplish the same objective, I've resorted to:

```
            $update = "UPDATE user SET weekday = 2 WHERE user_category=4 LIMIT 200";
            $this->db->query($update); 

            $update = "UPDATE user SET weekday = 2 WHERE user_category=4 LIMIT 200";
            $this->db->query($update); 

            $update = "UPDATE user SET weekday = 2 WHERE user_category=4 LIMIT 200";
            $this->db->query($update); 

            $update = "UPDATE user SET weekday = 2 WHERE user_category=4 LIMIT 200";
            $this->db->query($update); 

                    ...... all the way to the end. Of course I used a while loop to do the above.
```

Done and done.Thanks all for the help.